# how to Click and check the hyper Links in the table columns of webpage using Selenium web driver(Java code)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My question is simple- Using Selenium.Can anyone help me on this.I am using selenium in java.The webpage contain table with 5 columns.In the second column Hyperlinks lists are there.I would like to click each and every link in the second column one by one and check some criteria.
Please do the needful.Thanks in Advance.

=================================================================================

This is my Code Part:

WebElement table = d1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='search_results']/table"));

```
         // Now get all the TR elements from the table 
         List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
         //WebElement cell1 =allRows.get(1);
        // System.out.println("Table"+ allRows.get(1).getText());


         //System.out.println(allRows.size());
         // And iterate over them, getting the cells 
         for (WebElement row : allRows) { 
           List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td")); 
           for (WebElement cell : cells) { 
               String s = cell.getText();
```

==================================================================
This code is retrieving all table data's.I need to click each and everylink in the second column values(Hyperlinks) one by one and check some criteria.

=================================================================

It is showing "WebElements" cannot be a resolved type.This is my full code

public class Reading {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException, InterruptedException 
        {

```
     WebDriver d1= new FirefoxDriver();
     d1.get("https://fusion.paypal.com/fusionportal/");
     WebElement ds = d1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ext-gen176']/ul/li/a"));
     ds.click();
     WebElement dt = d1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ext-gen178_startDate']"));
     dt.sendKeys("20/11/2013");
     WebElement sc = d1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='searchDeploys']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]"));
     sc.click();
     Thread.sleep(2000);
     //WebElement table_element = d1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ext-gen236']"));
     //List<WebElement> tr=table_element.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='ext-gen236']"));
     WebElements links = d1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ext-gen238']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div"));

    for (WebElement link : links) {

       link.click();
     }
```

}
}

Comment: Have you tried anything? Is there something that doesn't work as you thought it should?

Comment: I have pasted my code.Please check and do the needful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to know without seeing the HTML as well, but assuming it's a regular table from the rest of your code, try something like

```
List<WebElement> links = d1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='search_results']/table/tr/td[2]/a"));
for (WebElement link: links) {
  link.click();
}
```

Comment: It should be List<WebElement>, not WebElements. Answer updated